# OptaPlanner iterating through custom moves in original order

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have a basic scheduling task where I'm trying to schedule activities in a list of time slots. I'm creating an initial solution where I assign activities pretty close to the time slot that they should end up in, e.g.:

```
activity a -> timeSlot 10  
activity b -> timeSlot 50  
activity c -> timeSlot 100
```

and what I want from this point is for OptaPlanner to simply move those activities backwards, one timeSlot at a time, until none of my hard or soft constraints are broken.

I've created a custom change move factory where I'm trying to do exactly that:

```
public List<Move> createMoveList(ActivityScheduler activityScheduler) {
    List<Move> moveList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<TimeSlot> timeSlotList = activityScheduler.getTimeSlotList();

    for (Activity activity : activityScheduler.getActivityList()) {
        for (int n = activity.getStartingTimeSlot().getIndex(); n >= 0; n--) {
            moveList.add(new TimeSlotChangeMove(activity, timeSlotList.get(n)));
        }
    }

    return moveList;
}
```

And I've set my selection order to ORIGINAL in my config:

```
<localSearch>
    <moveListFactory>
        <selectionOrder>ORIGINAL</selectionOrder>
        <moveListFactoryClass>...TimeSlotChangeMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
    </moveListFactory>
    ...
```

What I was hoping was that when it's moving say activity c, it would move it to timeSlot 99, then 98, 97 etc. until no constraints are broken. But that's not what's happening; e.g. one of the first steps shows:

```
2014-08-27 13:37:12.382 DEBUG 7401 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase  :  
Step index (1), time spend (326), score (-16hard/13soft), new best score (-16hard/13soft),  
accepted/selected move count (1000/2242) for picked step (Do Homework #2 -> Required Slots: 2   Starting TimeSlot: TimeSlot 2035 => TimeSlot 1240).
```

It moves the activity way too far back (from slot 2035 to 1240). How can I get OptaPlanner to move the activity only as far back as is needed and no further?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a `<constructionHeuristic>`, not a `<localSearch>`. Take a look at the docs chapter on Construction Heuristics.

If you do insist in using `<localSearch>`, configure a `<pickEarlyType>`. See docs on Local Search, section on `pickEarlyType`.

Comment: Ah...thanks for the response, but I still need some help. I used a simple first-fit construction heuristic (no local search), but this still didn't schedule things the way I want. If I have an activity that starts at slot 100, I want it to be moved backwards to slot 99, not slot 1, which is what's happening. A reading of the docs does not indicate how I could do this; can you provide any further insight?

Comment: Take a look at Planning Value Strength and Weakest Fit Decreasing in the docs.